# Clear / reset button (x) in input field not showing

Tags: html, css

The type 'input' in Input field puts an X symbol within it by default for clearing/resetting the text when run on **Internet Explorer** but doesn't show it when run on other browsers such as **Chrome**.
What would be the simplest solution to overcome this problem?

A simple input tag can illustrate the difference:

```
 <input />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the type to search: `<input type="search" />`. Then the clear button should appear but you might have to write something in there first.

Comment: Is it possible to modify its styles? The x buttons's.

Comment: Yes, using `-webkit-search-cancel-button`. Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/5XKrc/3/. This is for webkit-browsers only though (Chrome, Safari, Opera), so be aware it might not look the same in all browsers. As @feeela suggested you might want to have a look at `-ms-clear` as well

Comment: It did work on the simple input tag, but not on the one I'm using:

<input type="search" id="editableComponentNameValue" class="bwc-inputs-input editablePropertyInputValue" name="input" required="" placeholder="Component Name required" value="Davids Treedsfs" style="width: 70%; text-align: left; border-style: solid; cursor: text;">

Comment: Like this: `#editableComponentNameValue::-webkit-search-cancel-button{
    position:relative;
    right:5px;  
  
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius:10px;
    background: red;
}`

Comment: Worked perfectly fine. Another issue, its blue, the cross itself. I changed your code to:
#editableComponentNameValue::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    -webkit-appearance: searchfield-cancel-button;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
}
How do I make it black?
I put color and BG = black too, but to no avail.

Comment: You cannot style the default searchfield-cancel-button :/ But you can make it with linear gradient: http://jsfiddle.net/pcwudrmc/34133/

Answer (score 0):

The UI elements for forms are dependent on a combination of the operating system and used browser.

The easiest way to display very similar inputs, is to disable the special behaviors some browsers (especially mobile browsers) are using. In that case it is most probably `::-ms-clear`:

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-clear